# How is the second else invoked here after the cmp command?

Tags: bash

I don't really understand how the second `||` clause works. I understand that if the packages are different the `rm -r node_modules` is executed. I however don't understand how the second `||` works

```
cmp package.0.json node_modules/package.1.json || { rm -r node_modules || :; npm install; cp package.json node_modules/; }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `cmdA || cmdB` snippet means "Run `cmdA` and if it fails (exits with an exit code other than 0), run `cmdB`".

From https://stackoverflow.com/q/3224878/4482039: the colon `:` in bash is a command that does nothing.

Thus, the `rm -r node_modules || :; ...` snippet can be interpreted as:

1. Run `rm -r node_modules`.
2. If it fails (because the `node_modules` file/directory does not exist, or we don't have permissions), do nothing (ignore the error)
3. Run the rest of the line.

This is a way to ignore errors, because in this case errors are expected. Specifcally for `rm`, this way is safer than the `-f` flag because it doesn't force the removal of files `rm` would usually refuse to delete.

Comment: However, I do not know *why* ignoring errors this way is necessary, since `cmdA ; cmdB` means "Run `cmdA`, then run `cmdB` anyway"...

Comment: It does make a difference if `-e` is used e.g. for (the rest of) a script.

Answer (score 0):

`||` evaluates the right side only if the left side exit status is nonzero (usually it is when it fails). So, according to that the steps are:

1. `cmp package.0.json node_modules/package.1.json`
2. Only if the previous command fails then do the next steps
3. Run `rm -r node_modules`
4. If the step 3 fails then do nothing (`:` is like a *no-op* command)
5. Run `npm install`
6. Run `cp package.json node_modules/`